# What are the values in the Array cells_per_number refering to

Tags: ruby

This was a solution to a problem on GitHub.I was looking over the solution and I was wondering what the numbers in the array are referring to

LED Clock: You are (voluntarily) in a room that is completely dark except for
the light coming from an old LED digital alarm clock. This is one of those
clocks with 4 seven segment displays using an HH:MM time format. The clock is
configured to display time in a 24 hour format and the leading digit will be
blank if not used. What is the period of time between when the room is at its
darkest to when it is at its lightest?

```
def compute_brightness(units)
    cells_per_number = [ 6, 2, 5, 5, 4, 5, 6, 3, 7, 6 ]

    units.each_with_object({}) do |t, hash|
      digits = t.split('')
      hash[t] = digits.map { |d| cells_per_number[d.to_i] }.reduce(:+)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The numbers refer to the number of segments that are "on" when displaying the corresponding digit. When displaying the number "0," six segments are "on" (all except the center segment), so the number at index 0 is 6. When displaying 1, only two segments are "on," so the number at index 1 is 2. You get the idea.

```
    _                               _               _
0) | | = 6      1)   | = 2      2)  _| = 5      3)  _| = 5
   |_|               |             |_               _|

                    _               _               _
4) |_| = 4      5) |_  = 5      6) |_  = 6      7)   | = 3
     |              _|             |_|               |

    _               _
8) |_| = 7      9) |_| = 6
   |_|              _|
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jordan has answered your specific question, but the code isn't a complete solution to the stated problem. Here's a way of doing that.

```
lpd = { 0=>6, 1=>2, 2=>5, 3=>5, 4=>4, 5=>5, 6=>6, 7=>3, 8=>7, 9=>6 }

def min_leds(lpd, range)
  leds(lpd, range).min_by(&:last).first
end

def max_leds(lpd, range)
  leds(lpd, range).max_by(&:last)
end

def leds(lpd, range)
  lpd.select { |k,_| range.cover?(k) }
end

darkest = 
  [ *[
       [max_leds(lpd, (1..1)), max_leds(lpd, (0..2))],
       [[0,0], max_leds(lpd, (1..9))]
     ].max_by { |(_,a), (_,b)| a+b },
    max_leds(lpd, (0..5)),
    max_leds(lpd, (0..9))
  ].transpose.first.join.insert(2,':')
  #=> "10:08"

lightest = [0, min_leds(lpd, (1..9)),
            min_leds(lpd, (0..5)),
            min_leds(lpd, (0..9))
           ].join.insert(2,':')
  #=> "0111"
```

To make the solution more realistic, an array (possibly empty) of the locations of the burnt-out leds should be passed to the method.